# Does word ‘shampoo’ in this sentence mean 'hair'?

Tags: expressions, nouns

> One day at the salon, the stylist offers to give you a small trim with
>   your shampoo, like the lovely model in the magazine.

I've just read the above sentence,from book Breakfast at Tiffany's, the word 'shampoo' confused me a lot. It seems that here in the sentence, 'a small trim with your shampoo' means that the stylist will cut the writer's hair. *But I've googled that the world 'shampoo' is a hair care product, typically in the form of a viscous liquid, that is used for cleaning hair.*

How should we understand this sentence here?

Does it mean that the stylist will cut the hair of 'you' and also wash the hair with Shampoo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shampoo is also a verb, and then also a noun form of that verb.  So you have

1) original noun: *"A bottle of shampoo"*

2) verb:  *"I will shampoo your hair"*

3) new noun, from verb, describing the **process of shampooing**:  *"I've booked you in for a shampoo"*

This is all in the dictionary, eg http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shampoo

So, *"a small trim with your shampoo"* means *"A small trim in addition to us shampooing your hair"*.